# How can I remove words from an array that are after a new line?

Tags: php, arrays, split, explode

I want to get the strings after each `:` and before each `\n` from the following:

```
När:Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag\nVar:Främst norra Jämtland\nIntensitet:Väst ca 21 m/s\nKommentar:-
```

Source (`alert[4]->info->description` as of this question were asked): https://opendata-download-warnings.smhi.se/api/version/2/alerts.json

I've tried with `explode()` but after that, I am clueless of how I can remove `\nVar` and the others from the arrays.

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "När"
  [1]=>
  string(45) "Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag
Var"
  [2]=>
  string(34) "Främst norra Jämtland
Intensitet"
  [3]=>
  string(25) "Väst ca 21 m/s
Kommentar"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "-"
}
```

Here's how I want it to look like:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(45) "Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag"
  [1]=>
  string(34) "Främst norra Jämtland"
  [2]=>
  string(25) "Väst ca 21 m/s"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "-"
}
```

Here's how I tried so far:

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://opendata-download-warnings.smhi.se/api/version/2/alerts.json');
$content = json_decode($content);

foreach($content->alert AS $alert) {
    if($alert->info->area->areaDesc == '013') {
        $desc = explode(':', $alert->info->description);
        $descc = explode("\n", $desc);    # Don't know how to explode by \n since it returns an error; explode() expects parameter 2 to be string
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($desc); echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `Don't know how to explode by \n since it returns an error; explode() expects parameter 2 to be string` ehm... you're trying to explode an array as `$desc` is an array.

Comment: Ok. Didn't think about it that way :) Thank you, but the problem is still a problem since I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to capture what is between `:` and `\n`.

```
$text = "När:Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag\nVar:Främst norra Jämtland\nIntensitet:Väst ca 21 m/s\nKommentar:-";
preg_match_all("/\w+:(.*?)\\n/", $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => r:Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag

            [1] => Var:Främst norra Jämtland

            [2] => Intensitet:Väst ca 21 m/s

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag
            [1] => Främst norra Jämtland
            [2] => Väst ca 21 m/s
        )

)
```

https://3v4l.org/rpu5E

---

Sadly my regex mojo is not with me today...
So I had to switch to good old explode and array_functions.
I multiexplode the array on `:` and `\n` then I intersect the array on the uneven keys using range() to get the keys needed.

```
$text = "När:Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag\nVar:Främst norra Jämtland\nIntensitet:Väst ca 21 m/s\nKommentar:Sydväst 14-17 m/s. Avtagande söndag morgon.";

$exploded = multiexplode(array("\n",":"), $text);
if(count($exploded) > 2){
    $range = array_flip(range(1,count($exploded),2));
}else{
    $range = ["1" => 1];
}

$result = array_intersect_key($exploded, $range);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag
    [3] => Främst norra Jämtland
    [5] => Väst ca 21 m/s
    [7] => -
)
```

If you need 0 indexed array use array_values to reset the keys.
https://3v4l.org/tbgLM

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked wonderful, despite for when it comes to when `Kommentar:` is empty or are the only string in `$alert[int]->info->description`. That content returns empty, even if it have content in it, like this: `Kommentar:Natt till söndag och söndag morgon väst eller sydväst ca 15 m/s.` (same source, but for `$alert[0]->info->description` as of when this comment was written).

Comment: I just noticed. Working on a fix.

Comment: I did noticed a bug though. If I change the string in `$text` to `Kommentar:Sydväst 14-17 m/s. Avtagande söndag morgon.` I get the following errors: `Warning: range(): step exceeds the specified range in F:\Websites\www\vadret-justnu\index.php on line 18. Warning: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given in F:\Websites\www\vadret-justnu\index.php on line 18. Warning: array_intersect_key(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given in F:\Websites\www\vadret-justnu\index.php on line 18`

Comment: @Erik fixed it. Another option is an associative array like this: https://3v4l.org/ptE29

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
    <?php
function getContents($str, $startDelimiter, $endDelimiter) {
  $contents = array();
  $startDelimiterLength = strlen($startDelimiter);
  $endDelimiterLength = strlen($endDelimiter);
  $startFrom = $contentStart = $contentEnd = 0;
  while (false !== ($contentStart = strpos($str, $startDelimiter, $startFrom))) {
    $contentStart += $startDelimiterLength;
    $contentEnd = strpos($str, $endDelimiter, $contentStart);
    if (false === $contentEnd) {
      break;
    }
    $contents[] = substr($str, $contentStart, $contentEnd - $contentStart);
    $startFrom = $contentEnd + $endDelimiterLength;
  }

  return $contents;
}

$sample = 'När:Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag\nVar:Främst norra Jämtland\nIntensitet:Väst ca 21 m/s\nKommentar:-';
print_r( getContents($sample, ':', '\n') );
 ?>
```

**RESULT**

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Sent lördag kväll och natt till söndag
   [1] => Främst norra Jämtland
   [2] => Väst ca 21 m/s
 )
```

Comment: It only returns an empty array when I try it in my `foreach` loop with `$alert->info->description` instead of `$sample`. But it works fine if I use pure text (like in your answer).

Comment: How can it be possible. Are you using `class` or something wrong in the `$alert->info->description`